# f_a is a morse function

Tags: differential-geometry, morse-theory

How can I prove:
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^k\longrightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$, and, for each $a\in{\mathbb{R}^k}$ define $$f_a(x)=f(x)+a_1x_1+...+a_kx_k.$$
For almost all $a\in{\mathbb{R}^k}$, $f_a$ is a Morse function.

Comment: By definition a Morse function is a function whose critical points are non degenerate, that means that the matrix associated to the quadratic form at any critical point of f_a is invertible. So what you can do, firstly is compute the gradient of that function and see for which values of the x does vanish. Then compute the matrix associated to the quadratic form d^2 f and show that it does not vanish at that critical points you've found.

Comment: Are you sure that the function takes value in R^k and not in R ?

Comment: You're right, thank you. It has to be R.

Comment: [Word-by-word duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303653/transversality-and-morse-function)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$ not $\mathbb{R}^k$, otherwise, this is nonsense.

Let $g\colon\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ defined by:
$$g(x):=(\partial_{x_1}f(x),\ldots,\partial_{x_k}f(x)).$$
Then, notice that one has:
$$\mathrm{d}_xf_a=g(x)+a.$$
Therefore, $x$ is a critical point of $f_a$ if and only if $g(x)=-a$.

Assume that that $-a$ is a regular value of $g$ and let $x$ be a critical point of $f$, then $x$ is a non-degenerated critical point of $f$, since ${\mathrm{d}^2}_xf_a=\mathrm{d}_xg$ is surjective and thus invertible.

Finally, using Sard's theorem for almost all $a$, $-a$ is a regular value of $g$, so that for almost all $a$, $f_a$ is a Morse function.